# Webpack: mini-css-extract-plugin not outputting css file

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass

I think I followed the documentation correctly, but it does not work at all.

What I want is to generate a css file, and do not load it in style tags with js.

In my src directory:: "scss/custom.scss" and "style.scss", and none of them is generated in output.

EDIT: src code: https://github.com/marcosroot/webpackexample

My settings are:

```
const path = require('path');
const BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const devMode = true;

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './src/toggle_menu.js',
        './src/calls_apis.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: devMode ? 'main.js' : 'main.[hash].js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new BundleTracker({
            filename: './webpack-stats.json'
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: devMode ? '[name].css' : '[name].[hash].css'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'scss/custom.scss'),
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'postcss-loader',
                    'sass-loader',
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need provide relative path to your output. I have a next config in my project `new MiniCssExtractPlugin({filename: DEV ? '../css/_.css' : '../css/_-[contenthash].css'}),`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your trouble is coming from a wrong path resolution in your configuration :

```
include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'scss/custom.scss'),
```

It means to webpack to include only a resource located under `{root}/scss/custom.scss` and, given your explanation, I presume the right path should be `{root}/src/scss/custom.scss`.

So to include your two files `{root}/src/scss/custom.scss` and `{root}/src/styles.scss` and any other scss files under `src` folder, you can use :

```
module: {
    rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            include: /src/, // <-- Change here ---------------------
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                'css-loader',
                'postcss-loader',
                'sass-loader',
            ]
        }
    ]
},
```

You can also simply remove `include` option if you're pretty sure there's no other roaming scss files in your project or node modules that may be found and should not be bundled at the same time (that's probably the case).

You can also supply an array of the two files by adding src in the path resolution :

```
include: [
   path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/scss/custom.scss'),
   path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/styles.scss'),
]
```

****** EDIT *******

Following your comment and from your repo, there's another few mistakes :

- `postcss-loader` is not included as dev dependency and no configuration for it as well
- You mistake what is the `include` option of a rule. It does simply mean that only resources that are matching the include test will be processed like configured in that rule. **You still need to require the scss files at some point in your script**.

I've [forked your repo](https://github.com/liqueurdetoile/webpackexample) and set up a correct configuration with scss import in call_api.js (one of your entry point). Build and you will see the css file in the dist folder (I've set up a dumb cssnano config for postcss, that will be parsed harsh)

Answer (score 26):

This question is relatively old but I ran into the same problem and I wanted to share my solution. This is probably very dependent on your configuration, but anyway, my `mini-css-extract-plugin` did not work because:

- I ran it with `webpack -p` (which an alias for production mode + minify)
- The css rule I had setup did not clarify that it made side effects.

As a result, when I ran the build in production mode (i.e. `webpack -p`), it did not produce an output because when webpack saw this…

```js
import './my-css-file.css';
```

…and was like "that doesn't do anything, i'll remove it from your build".

---

So in order to tell webpack that this type of file matters, you have to mark the rule as `sideEffects: true`

```js
// ...
module.exports = {
  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
        include: [/* fill this in */],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        // 
        sideEffects: true, //  ADD THIS
        // 
      },
    ],
  },
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for adding this.  I was dealing with this same issue when managing a rule for css modules and a rule for non css modules.  The non css module rule was essentially removed the bundle and I couldn't figure out why.  Sure enough this worked as expected.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed as well.

Answer (score 2):

*Not for Op's case. But in My Case:* 
*(I dont have sufficient knowledge on the reason)*

it seems you must **remove `'style-loader'`**, when you use `MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader`.

- (Also, if you place `MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader` before `'style-loader'`, no Error will show & you wont notice it.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide relative path in your filename or specify `publicPath: '../'` in your loader config https://www.npmjs.com/package/mini-css-extract-plugin#minimal-example

In my project I have

```
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({filename: DEV ? '../css/styles.css' : '../css/styles-[contenthash].css'}),
```

Documentation provides example with public path

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
      // both options are optional
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              // you can specify a publicPath here
              // by default it use publicPath in webpackOptions.output
              publicPath: '../'
            }
          },
          "css-loader"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```